# Google Sheet to Excel conversion - Treating "" as zero

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I need to convert several (hundreds) Google Sheets to Excel. For the sake of tidiness, many cells in the original sheets have "" in them as a result of formulas like `=IF(condition is true;calculation;"")`.

Google Sheet treats "" as zero. For instance, A1="", B1=3, A1+B1=3.

When this sheet is exported to Excel, Excel gives a data type error for A1+B1. The error goes away if A1 is changed to blank or 0.

Is there a simple way to make Excel behave like Google Sheet in this instance?

Comment: You can use SUM(): `=SUM(A1,B1)` which will ignore the text.  Most formulas will do that, some do not, but most.  otherwise no there is no way in Excel to do that, outside of changing all the `""` to `0` and using a custom number format that hides the `0` to appear blank.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I was really hoping I would not have to go around all the sheets and start tweaking the formulas and number formats. It could take me several days of tedious work :-(

Comment: Can you fix the formula in google to change the false result as 0 instead of ""? If you changed the false result to "false" (not in quotes) in the formula it should import as a 0.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Yes, I can certainly do this kind of thing. However, the problem is that I have to convert hundreds of sheets, many of which are fairly large with many complex formulas. This should be a trivial process handled by the conversion process or by the way Excel treats "" in calculations.

Answer (score 0):

André, you can apply this script on each of the sheets of your spreadsheets to delete "" in the formulas, so that there is no effect neither on the sheets, nor on Excel

```
function myFunction() {

var feuilles = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
feuilles.forEach(function(feuille){
 var cellules = feuille.getRange(1,1,feuille.getLastRow(),feuille.getLastColumn())
  var formules = cellules.getFormulas()
  const regex = new RegExp(';["]{2}', 'g')
  var li = 0
  formules.forEach(function(ligne){
    li++
    var co = 0
    ligne.forEach(function(formule){
      co++
      try{
        if(regex.test(formule)){
          formule = formule.replace(regex,';')
          feuille.getRange(li,co).setFormula(formule)
        }
      }
      catch(e){}
    })
  })
})
  
}
```